# how do I change the color of output of a table created by using function called "datatable" from DT package in R?

Tags: r, datatable

how do I change the color of output of a table created by using function called "datatable" from DT package in R?

here of the code for creating the table
I used DT package for 'datatable' function

Thank you!!

```
Hrs2Resolve98PercentTicketsDataTable <- datatable(data = Hrs2Resolve98PercentTicketsData,
                                     , options = list(bLengthChange = FALSE
                                                      , bFilter = FALSE
                                                      , bInfo = FALSE
                                                      , ordering = FALSE
                                                      , bPaginate = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DT::formatStyle()` to format `DT::datatable`s.

Example:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui=DT::formatStyle(DT::datatable(mtcars),
                     columns=0:ncol(mtcars),
                     backgroundColor="blue"),
  server = function(input,output){}
)
```

More examples using `formatStyle` can be seen [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html).

Comment: Sorry, I meant to change the color of the numbers, not the background of the table. Thanks!

Comment: 'formatStyle' additionally has a 'color' argument that will allow you to change the font color. there's an example on [this page](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html)